# Cast int to long in Java

Tags: java, int

This questions has many answers and I have seen them. I have code that has been working but today suddenly it starting throwing `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long`
 for the line

```
return null == input.get(keyName) ? 0L : (long) input.get(keyName);
```

Error is coming from `(long) input.get(keyName)`. I wonder why it starting breaking all of sudden. `(long) input.get(keyName)` this looks good to me.
I thought of doing `((Integer) input.get(keyName)).longValue()` but was getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer` as map sometimes contains `long` values. Any suggestions

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at accountservice.adapter.batch.testJob.SyncDriverPartitioner.getLongValueFromMap(SyncDriverPartitioner.java:78) ~[classes/:?]
    at accountservice.adapter.batch.testJob.SyncDriverPartitioner.partition(SyncDriverPartitioner.java:47) ~[classes/:?]
    at accountservice.adapter.batch.testJob.SyncDriverPartitioner$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6f3315e4.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this, and if both branches of the ternary expression return the same type, I wouldn't neccesarily expect a problem.  Please add a reproducible example.

Comment: What's the type of `input.get(keyName)`? And what kind of objects are in that map at runtime? Do you have a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we could look at?

Comment: Please post your stacktrace and the relevant code

Comment: Map<String,Object> is mapType. Objects are both int and long values. Let me see if I can reproduce with small test

Comment: why not `Map<String,Long> ` ?

Comment: It is a map returned from `Map<String, Object> countMinMaxResult =
        jdbcTemplate.queryForMap(countMinMaxQuery, transactionDate.toString());`

Comment: Do `((Number)input.get(keyName)).longValue()`

Comment: `(Number)input.get(keyName)).longValue()` is working. Just want to know why it started breaking suddenly. I have seen many posts that says `(long) input.get(keyName)` is correct

Comment: Nothing happens suddenly. You're the only one really in a position to figure out what changed.

Comment: May be. I will look into it. Thanks @shmosel

Comment: Ok I found the issue. Someone changed the database column datatype from BIGINT to INTEGER

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that all numeric primitive wrappers extend `java.lang.Number`:

```
return null == input.get(keyName) ? 0L : ((Number) input.get(keyName)).longValue();
```

As to why it started giving errors suddenly; really the only likely reason is that up until it started failing, you were always putting `java.lang.Long` objects in the `input` Map, and it changed so you're also putting `java.lang.Integer` in them now.

It's quite easy for that to happen with auto-boxing and numeric constants:

```
long v = 42;
input.put("key", v);  // Puts a java.lang.Long in the map
input.put("key", 42); // Puts a java.lang.Integer in the map
input.put("key", 42L); // Puts a java.lang.Long in the map
```

You can avoid it by declare your Map type-safely (`Map<String, Long>`). If you do that, `input.put("key", 42)` will give a compile-time error.

Comment: Not sure which one is the best practice I also tried `Long.valueOf(input.get(keyName).toString())` and it works fine.

Comment: That approach first converts anything to a String, and then parses it again as a number. It is less efficient, but also more risky from a maintenance perspective. What if the value wasn't a number? Maybe you accidentally put in a String "hello world". With a cast to Number, you get an error message that is clear and easy to trace to the root cause (wrong type of object in the map). With your suggestion you get a NumberFormatException - it will take you longer to trace that back to the cause - you put the wrong type of object in the map.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than casting an int to a long I would suggest:

```
return null == input.get(keyName) ? 0L : Integer.toUnsignedLong(input.get(keyName))
```

At least this way you should get some more information about why it cannot be converted to a long rather than just a ClassCastException

***Answer Update***

Based on your comments I guess you are going to have to check type of the entry in Map before processing it, I would suggest the following:

```
    Object keyValue = input.get(keyName);
    if (null == keyValue) return 0L;
    String valueType = keyValue.getClass().getTypeName();
    if (valueType.equals(Long.class.getTypeName())) {
        return (long) keyValue;
    }
    if (valueType.equals(Integer.class.getTypeName())) {
        return Integer.toUnsignedLong((int) keyValue);
    }
    throw new TypeMismatchException(String.format("Type '%s' is not supported...", valueType));
```

This will let you define different operations for different types of entry, it is extendable to any types you want to support.  You can tweak the exception thrown as well to provide you relevant information.

The snippet above shows you the actual type so that you can extend your code to support that type, or work out why something of that type got into your map.

It should be noted that it would probably be better to do this when data is entered into the map, not when it's taken out of the map.  In which case you should be able to change your map to a type .  It's always better to sanitise your imputes than trying to deal with a mishmash of mixed data types at a later date.

Comment: `Integer.toUnsignedLong` excepts int as input but in my case `input.get(keyName)` is Object as Map<String, Object>.

Comment: Updated the answer based on your comments